# Companies House Rate Limit Handling with ratelimit library

Tags: api, python-requests, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429, exponential-backoff

I am working with the [companies house API](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/index/gettingStarted/rateLimiting.html) to extract several thousands [profiles of companies](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/readCompanyProfile.html).

The normal ratelimit is 600/5 minutes, but can be extended to 1200/5 minutes. I used this script last week and it was working fine for several hours, now i keep getting a 429 error.

I think the script is fine, but i might be missing something with the decorators from the `ratelimit` and `backoff` libraries, maybe someone is more familiar with those libraries and sees a logic error I am not seeing.

```
# api_funcs.py module

import requests
from requests import ConnectionError
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry
from backoff import on_exception, expo
from pipeline_tools.helpers import get_key    

KEY = get_key("API_key")

FIVE_MINUTES = 300  # Number of seconds in five minutes.


@sleep_and_retry  # if we exceed the ratelimit imposed by @limits forces sleep until we can start again.
@on_exception(expo, ConnectionError, max_tries=5)
@limits(calls=1200, period=FIVE_MINUTES)
def call_api(url, api_key):

    r = requests.get(url, auth=(api_key, ""))

    if not (r.status_code == 200 or r.status_code == 404):
        r.raise_for_status()

    elif r.status_code == 404:
        return dict({"error": "not found"})

    else:
        return r.json()

def company_basic_search(comp_code):
    return call_api(url=API_BASE_URL+"/company/"+comp_code, api_key=KEY)

# [list of 200,000 company codes]
comp_codes = ['XXX1','XXX2','XXX3'] 

for code in comp_codes:
    basic_profile_resource = company_basic_search(comp_code=code)
    # if-elif-else flow inserting the object in error table if 404 or in other table if 200.
```

I keep getting a

`raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: ...`

Is there anything wrong with my logic or this is probably on the API side?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine - it was a problem on CH server's side, whose actual limit was lower than the one reported on the documentations.